# why does configure recent glibc complain that nptl is not there?

Tags: linux, glibc

I am trying to recompile a recent (2.12.1) `glibc`, following the directions in

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Glibc-Install-HOWTO/

From a build directory I do

```
../*2.12.1/configure --prefix=/usr/local_another --enable-add-ons='linuxthreads'
```

and I get

```
*** On GNU/Linux systems it is normal to compile GNU libc with the
*** `nptl' add-on.  Without that, the library will be
*** incompatible with normal GNU/Linux systems.
*** If you really mean to not use this add-on, run configure again
*** using the extra parameter `--disable-sanity-checks'.
```

So it looks like `configure` wants `ntpl`.  OK, following the above HOWTO, I change to

```
../*2.12.1/configure --prefix=/usr/local_another --enable-add-ons='linuxthreads ntpl'
```

and now I get this error:

```
configure: error: add-on directory "ntpl" does not exist
```

GNU documentation says that since `glibc 2.6`, `ntpl` is part of `glibc`, and in any case I can't find this package separately anywhere.

So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you keep trying to enable linuxthreads, which is ancient and obsolete.

Comment: Thank you, this is what the HOWTO told me, let me try the way you recommend.

Comment: Also got rid of `ntpl`, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's `nptl` (Native POSIX Thread Library) and not `ntpl`, that's why are you getting the second error.